# JQuery To Change Back Color Of ASP:GridView Row

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, gridview

I am attempting to use JQuery for when a checkbox is unchecked change the color of the row to grey.  I am attempting to use this CSS class, and call it from JQuery.  However, I get no errors, and the row color is not changed.  How would I change the row color on the checkbox "uncheck"?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".Grid input:checkbox").each(function () {
            this.onclick = function ()
            {
                if (!this.checked)
                {
                    $(this).closest('tr').css('grdCell');
                }
            }
        })
        $('.Grid').find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    });
</script>


.grdCell {
    background-color: Gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the way to add a class to an element in jquery. To do that use `$(this).closest('tr').addClass('grdCell')`

You can either use the jquery `addClass('.grdCell')` or 
`css('background-color','Gray')`

Comment: I tried this $(this).closest.('tr').addClass('grdCell') but I get an error of unexpected token (

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in cs file:
GridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.Add("BackColor", "#CCCCCC");

Comment: This looks more like a comment than answer.